# ModernCV error : "Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex""

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, texstudio, moderncv

I modified the modern CV template and I have used the `Calibri` font. Don't know why but I just got this error. I did not this error when I ran this, maybe 1 year ago, did not get this error. Surprised to see this error now. I use `Build&View` to run the latex and view the PDF. Now it is giving this error without PDF.

[image]

Update1:
[image]

Update2: I have the fonts stored in the same folder
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell TeX Studio to use LuaLaTeX by adding a line with

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
```

at the beginning of your document. While normally lines starting with `%` are comments, TeX Studio interprets lines starting with `% !TeX`  as instructions how to run the underlying TeX engine/which engine to choose. Here we ask TeX Studio to run ``` lualatex`` instead of the default ``` pdflatex` which doesn't support modern font formats.

These special comments are not interpreted by TeX itself (which sees them as comments) but by the editor, so they are [documented in the manual of the editor](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#TEXCOM).

Beside that, having spaces in filenames can often cause trouble and might break in some versions. But since you use Windows anyway and therefore probably have Calibri installed as a system font, you can just load it with

```
\setsansfont{Calibri}
```

and therefore avoid having to mess with local font files.

Comment: I got some error. I have edited the question with response I got. Hope I have typed  at right place in the document. I am curious to know that `%` makes the whole line a comment. But how come TexStudio read and understand it. Thanks

Comment: The `%` makes the line a comment for TeX itself, but TeX Studio uses thids kind of comment in an earlier stage to decide which TeX engine to call. Details can be found [in the manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#TEXCOM)

Comment: @Mainland Do you have these font files installed on your system?

Comment: No. I did not install them or I don't know how to install them. What I did was saving the font files in the same folder and importing them in the file. Please, see my updated question.

Comment: @Mainland What happens if you just use `\setsansfont{Calibri}`?

Comment: My apologies. Now It worked flaw lessely. You know what I did, removed the spaces in the imported font file names. If you read the errors carefully, it is saying that `CalibriBold` not available when the file is named `Calibri Bold`. I removed spaces and it did the wonder. Thanks a ton for the answer.

Comment: One more update. I did what you said and it worked flawlessly. Thanks a ton. I will use this.

Comment: @Mainland I personally think that spaces in filenames are always a bad idea, but it should have worked anyway. I'll look into fixing this. Great that the other idea worked, it will probably use your system version of Calibri though instead of the local files.

Comment: You are correct. Don't why I did not think about it. Also, I am using `TeXstudio 2.12.22 (git 2.12.22) Using Qt Version 5.12.1, compiled with Qt 5.12.1 R`. Do you think I have to update it. Thanks

Comment: One more: I just ran the program without your first suggestion `%!  ...LuLatex`. It did not work. So it is needed. Also, how come TexStudio able to read this line though it is a comment starting with `%`.

Comment: @Mainland The TeX version is more important for this than the TeXStudio version, but in any case I don't think that updating would help with this right now. Generally though I think that it's always a good idea to keep your software up-to-date.